# How do I tell when a CUPS print jobs has been completed plus info about that job?

Tags: macos, printing, cups, kqueue

I need to know each time a Mac print job is created/completed, plus some information about that job (what was printed, pages, copies, etc).

The best method I've come up with thus far is to use kqueue() on /var/spool/cups/ and then parse the c##### files as they're created, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: This might get more responses on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think about creating a filter that you can put into the CUPS pipeline that collects this information and stores it for you (say in a database).  Then you can access the database to get the information using any standard database access mechanism.  Basically the filter is just a command-line program that gets a number of parameters passed to it from CUPS and needs to read input on stdin and write it to stdout.   You can find more information at http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-filter.html.

Comment: I like this idea a lot. Any ideas on how I could tell when a job had been canceled using this route?

Comment: I think that there are some methods to communicate with the backend.  I haven't actually implemented a filter for CUPS, though I did work on some LPR filters back in the day.  See the section on communicating with the backend.  You'd have to be working with a backend that writes device status back to the filter, but I would think that most do so that page counting software can easily hook into it and do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever looked what the **page_log** file provides for you? There's a man page providing details about its format. Recent versions of CUPS will let you configure the amount of info logged in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the *IPP subscription* schemes supported by CUPS?

These could trigger a *mailto:* or an *rss:* notification upon certain print system events. The IPP operations related to this topic are:

- `Create-Job-Subscriptions, Create-Printer-Subscriptions, Create-Resource-Subscriptions, Create-System-Subscriptions`

Details about this feature are in the CUPS Programming Manual:

- https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html